# Easy rails deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment

I want to deploy a small rails application. What is the easiest / fastest way to do so? Capistrano seems to be oversized for small applications.

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but I was looking for an alternative for capistrano. Like vflad, moonshine or something like that.

Answer (score 8):

I can't recommend [heroku](http://heroku.com/) enough. Deployment is as simple as a git push and there's a free service.

Comment: Seconding Heroku for what you listed. That's going to be hard to beat in the easy/fast department.

Answer (score 2):

You could try out [EngineYard](http://www.engineyard.com/) if you would prefer to not have to worry too much about infrastructure issues and focus on developing your application. They have a gem you can install on your system and the command "ey deploy" will deploy your app! [Here is a list of commands.](http://www.engineyard.com/products/appcloud/features/cli) Highly recommended!

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Vlad the Deployer](http://www.rubyhitsquad.com/Vlad_the_Deployer.html).

Seems to be a simpler deployment solution than Capistrano.